# Java if condition in cycle return wrong result

Tags: java

I new to programming and I am currently experiencing a problem, that I can't solve by myself. I've the following code: 
    package Ideas;

```
public class IdeaTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    int a;
    int b = 1;
    for (int x = 30; x >= 1; x--) {
        if (x >= 21) {
            a = 1;
        } else if (x >= 11 && x < 20) {

            a = 2;
        } else {

            a = 3;
        }
        int sum = a + b;
        counter++;
        System.out.printf("  %d.  " + " %d \n", counter, sum);
    }
}
}
```

Everything seems to work, but output shows the wrong result when x become equal to 11:

8. 2
9. 2
10. 2

    **11.   4**
11. 3
12. 3
13. 3

Maybe someone can explain, what's the problem, because changing conditions have no effect.
Thank you!

Comment: Well, what value were  you expecting?

Comment: `Changing conditions have no effect` There's no way this is true.

Comment: You need to explain what you expect this to do...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are printing 4, when x equals 20. When x equals 11, you are printing 3. If you put a break on the last else, you will see you will only enter it when x equals 20 or x is less than 11. Also, your output is printing the value that is stored in the variable counter, not x. If you want to print 3 when x equals 20, you must change to `else if(x >= 11 && x <= 20)`. Hope this helps.